# When proving a set is not regular is it enough to prove a subset of it regular?

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

E.g. when proving $L = \{w \in \{a,b\}^*:$
the first, the middle, and the last characters of w are identical$\}$, can i just prove $ab^{p}ab^{p}a$ is not regular? Where $p$ is the pumping length?

Comment: When asked a question about languages in general, first ask yourself what happens for the trivial languages, the empty set and the universal set ($\Sigma^*$). In this case, you can use the fact that that the empty set is a subset of every other language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mixed up a few things here. Say, L is indeed regular. Then the pumping lemma guarantees us **a** pumping length.

If we want to show that $L$ is **not** regular, we can go on by assuming its regular and for every pumping length we **find a word that cant be pumped.**

This means, we need to search for a word (for example $ab^pab^pa$ as you have suggested) and show that no matter how you divide this word into the 3 pieces $x,y,z$ ($w=xyz$) of the pumping lemma, you can find an integer $n$ with $xy^nz\notin L$. This would contradict the pumping lemma and therefore the regularity of $L$.

As a side note, showing that a **subset** of $L$ is not regular doesnt imply that also $L$ is not regular (for example, $\Sigma^*$ is regular, but there are non-regular languages which are obviously subsets of it).

Comment: Yeah i am having trouble with pumping lemma. Hmm, ...

Comment: My suggestion was different by the way.

Comment: Yes i noticed it only now -_- ill fix it :)

Comment: Any anyways, taking $a^pb^pa^pb^pa^p$ *should* work. Try to think what are all of the possible ways to partition this into 3 segment

Answer (score 1):

I think L is irregular. Let's assume it is. Then $\{ab\}^*$ has an irregular subset, but is clearly regular. On the other hand, L has an irregular subset (L itself) but is irregular. So you can't conclude anything from the irregularity of a subset.

And both the empty language and any language with a single element are regular, so any language, regular or irregular, has a regular subset. Again, it proves nothing.